# Getting SVN url of all branches using single line command

Tags: bash, svn, xargs

I am trying to retrieve svn url of all branches os a repository . I got the result using a simple bash script .
Can I do the same using "xargs" . I've no grip over the xargs command .

I tried something like this

```
svn ls https://my.svn.net/svn/projectA/branches | xargs -0 -I {} svn info {}\ ;
```

This prints the result of svn ls only .

Any Idea ?

**EDIT**

Out put of svn ls

```
svn ls https://my.svn.net/svn/projectA/branches

branch1
branch2
branch3
branch4
```

expected output while using xargs

```
https://my.svn.net/svn/projectA/branches/branch1
https://my.svn.net/svn/projectA/branches/branch2
...
...
```

Comment: @Inian edited orignial post .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just drop the `-0` flag from `xargs` which is meant for reading `NULL` de-limited output, just do

```
svn ls https://my.svn.net/svn/projectA/branches | xargs -I {} svn info "{}"
```

Here, the output from the `svn ls ..` is pipe-lined to `xargs` and are stored in `{}` which acts as a placeholder for the received values, then `svn info` is called upon each of the branch to provide the information you want. Notice the double quotes around `{}`, added to prevent your output from `svn ls` to undergo [Word-Splitting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit) done by the shell.

Quoting from the `man` page of `xargs`,

> -0, --null
>
> Input items are terminated by a ***null character instead of by whitespace***, and the quotes and backslash are not special (every character is taken literally).  Disables the end of file  string,
>                 which is treated like any other argument.  Useful when input items might contain white space, quote marks, or backslashes.  The GNU find *-print0* option produces input suitable for this mode.

From the comments, it looks like as if you would want to append the `URL` each of the branch name, you can do it as

```
svn ls https://my.svn.net/svn/projectA/branches | \
    xargs -I {} svn info "https://my.svn.net/svn/projectA/{}"
```

---

Not relevant to the current answer. Also if you are using `GNU xargs` you could use its `-r` flag to ensure the command is not running on a empty input from the pipeline.

```
xargs -r -I {} svn info "https://my.svn.net/svn/projectA/{}"
```

A `man` page reference,

> -r, --no-run-if-empty
>
> If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.  This option is a *GNU extension*.

Comment: thanx @Inian  . This will work  if you have all the branches checkout and you are running from the parent directory . Expanding your solution further for a url based command .


 svn ls https://my.svn.net/svn/projectA/branches | xargs -I {} svn info https://my.svn.net/svn/projectA/branches/"{}"